# Remove added set of rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$(document).on('click', '#add', function () {
    var newItemHTML = "<tr class='additionalcomplainant'><td><center><input type='text' name='' id='' /><br> <small><i>First Name</i></small></center></td><td><center><input type='text' name='' id='' /><br> <small><i>Middle Name</i></small></center></td><td><center><input type='text' name='' id='' /><br> <small><i>Last Name</i></small> </center></td></tr><tr class='additionalcomplainant'><td><center><input type='text' name='' id='' /><br> <small><i>City/Province</i></small></center></td><td><center><input type='text' name='' id=''/><br> <small><i>Town/Municipality</i></small></center></td><td><center><input type='text' name='' id='caseinfocomplaintlname' /><br> <small><i>Barangay/District</i></small></center></td> </tr><tr class='additionalcomplainant'><td><center><input type='text' name= id='' /><br> <small><i>Contact Number</i></small></center></td></tr>";
    $("table#t1table tr").last().before(newItemHTML);
});

$(document).on('click', '#remove', function () {

});
```

This is how i add row in my table using jquery. How would i remove the same set of rows on another button click. I want to remove these rows if for example the user mis-clicked the button and there is more than rows than needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could keep a reference to the added rows:

```
var addedRows = [];
$(document).on('click', '#add', function() {
    var $row = $("<tr class='additionalcomplainant'><td><center><input type='text' name='' id='' /><br> <small><i>First Name</i></small></center></td><td><center><input type='text' name='' id='' /><br> <small><i>Middle Name</i></small></center></td><td><center><input type='text' name='' id='' /><br> <small><i>Last Name</i></small> </center></td></tr><tr class='additionalcomplainant'><td><center><input type='text' name='' id='' /><br> <small><i>City/Province</i></small></center></td><td><center><input type='text' name='' id=''/><br> <small><i>Town/Municipality</i></small></center></td><td><center><input type='text' name='' id='caseinfocomplaintlname' /><br> <small><i>Barangay/District</i></small></center></td> </tr><tr class='additionalcomplainant'><td><center><input type='text' name= id='' /><br> <small><i>Contact Number</i></small></center></td></tr>");
    addedRows.push($row);
    $("#t1table tr").last().before($row);
});

$(document).on('click', '#remove', function() {
    var $row = addedRows.pop();
    if ($row) $row.remove();
});
```

In the above code, I keep an array. The added rows are *pushed* to the end on addition, and they're removed (using `pop`) from the end on removal. An advantage is that would still work if you decide to add at random places in the table.

Or, assuming there aren't any other `.additionalcomplainant` row than the one you add, you may do

```
$(document).on('click', '#remove', function() {
    $('#t1table .additionalcomplainant').last().remove();
});
```

As an aside, don't use `"table#t1table"` as selector: `"#t1table"` is identical and faster.

Comment: Best answer. It makes no assumptions about which row was added when removing.

Comment: one question it is only limited to one deletion?how about if i want to remove 2 or more rows?just want to clarify

Comment: If you want to be able to remove the last row with class additionalcomplainant in the table at every click, just use the second solution.

Comment: yeah i saw the updated a bit late..i also came up with that but i want to remove them by set is it possible?when i say by set. i mean the one added will also be remove, `like undo` , like the first solution?the only thing i had with the first one is i does not second click only first

Comment: @Pekka Then use a variation of my first solution (updated to use a stack, thus storing all added rows)

Comment: @DenysSéguret thanks for explanation i didnt think of this solution this is too complicated for my level now. i would upvote if i can but unfortunately i cant this is a good answer many will be helped

Comment: @Pekka I've added some comments. Is this clear now ?

Comment: @DenysSéguret yes it is clear because of the comment

Comment: `"Names":[{"lname":"Dela Cruz","mname":"Tamad","fname":"Juan"},{"lname":"Sha","mname":"Ryu","fname":"Ken"}]` Sir for example i want to put these values into the input text how would i put inside these dynamically generated input text

Answer (score 1):

**Option # 1**

Remove by class name. You added rows with classname = "additionalcomplainant", thus you can simply delete them using CSS selector for this class

```
$(document).on('click', '#remove', function () {
    $(".additionalcomplainant").remove();
});
```

**Option # 2**

When you add new rows add some temporary classname to them. If you want to delete them use selector for this class. If you want to add some rows after last "add" operation then remove temporary class from added rows and add it again to recently added.

```
$(document).on('click', '#add', function () {
    var tbl = $("table#t1table tr");
    var newRows = $(...).addClass('extraRows');
    tbl.find('tr').removeClass('extraRows');
    tbl.last().before(newRows);
});

$(document).on('click', '#remove', function () {
    $("table#t1table tr").find(".extraRows").remove();
});
```

**Option # 3**

If this classname is not unique and you cannot change it, then remember how much rows were inside table before addition and remove those that are outside that range

```
var options.rows = {
    rowsCount : 0
};

$(document).on('click', '#add', function () {
    var tbl = $("table#t1table tr");
    var newRows = ...
    options.rows = tbl.find('tr').length;
    tbl.last().before(newRows);
});

$(document).on('click', '#remove', function () {
    $("table#t1table tr").find("tr:gt(" + options.rows + ")")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the last row,

```
$(document).on('click', '#remove', function () {

    $("table#t1table tr:last").remove()

});
```

Comment: It's not the last row of the table.

Answer (score 0):

To append to the table:

```
$('#myTable tbody').append(newItemHTML);
```

To remove added rows:

```
$('#myTable .additionalcomplainant:last').remove();
```

Comment: This woud remove all the rows having that class, not just the last one.